# logout from current jsp page to a login page

Tags: java, javascript

I have a problem.
I have used a jsp page which contains multiple frames.In one of these frames there is logout button. If i logout only that part changes and not the whole page(as frame is just a view).
So the question is how can i make the whole jsp page(The one containng multiiple frames) to transit to login page back??

Comment: i believe that when you doing logout you are doing some sort of backed process invalidating user session etc, once that done redirect user to the desired page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is to add `target="_top"` to your link or you can use javascript to navigate using your top frame:

```
self.parent.location= "Logout URL";
```

Take a look at this for reference :

```
<a href="log_me_out.jsp" target="_top">LINK</a>

<a href="javascript://" onclick="self.parent.location='log_me_out.jsp'">LINK</a>
```

Or else, what you can do is, into logged out page, add a javascript code to remove the frames redirecting your document to the top frame:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  if (self.parent.frames.length != 0){
    self.parent.location=document.location.href;
   }
</script>
```